# in mysql database,how to upload the modified data from csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, data-migration, load-data-infile

Initially, I created a database called "sample" and updated the data from massive size CSV file.

Whenever I have small changes in .csv file (some data are added/deleted/modified), I have to update this in database too. Always updating the entire .csv file (large) is not efficient.

Is there any efficient way to update the modified data from .csv file to database?

Comment: using the following query "LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE sample;"

Comment: That is the only functionality available -- I wouldn't want to code similar functionality by hand, and it is optimized.  How much data is changing?  Because I'd look at scripting for specific tables rather than wholesale refreshing (if not from a mysqldump).

Comment: we cant say how much data gets changed ..for some times we can get more changes and some times we can get minimal chages in some fields.

Comment: You need to get whomever is updating the data to be doing it in the database, not externally.  Otherwise, break up the CSV file into multiple smaller ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using LOAD DATE INFILE for importing from CSV, try using this syntax:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE `tbl_name`
...
...
```

IGNORE keyword will skip any rows in the CSV that duplicate any existing row in the table causing a conflict with a unique key. Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

This will be more quicker and efficient than importing the complete CSV again.